# Get all parent paths from Path String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I need some advice concerning string manipulation. This is a possible string:

```
"/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile"
```

What I need is an array with the following in it:

```
 ['/branches', '/branches/projects','/branches/projects/MyTool','/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool']
```

So to clarify what this array should contain: All parent paths to the last file or folder. The last file or folder is excluded in the array.

I know I can split the string at `"/"` and then could iterate over the array, concatenate strings and delete the last entry from the array. This method I would call recursively until there is no element in the array left. The concatenated string would then be saved at every iteration to a new array which would hold the desired result at the end......

However I asked me how to do it very clean and simple and I am sure someone of you can come up with a superb solution :)

**EDIT**
Here is my current solution I came up with just now:

```
var string = "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/anotherFolderOrFile";
var helperArr = string.split("/");
var endArray = [];

getParentArray();
console.log(endArray);

function getParentArray() {
    if(helperArr.length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var helperString = "";
        for(var i = 0;i<helperArr.length;i++) {
            helperString = helperString+helperArr[i];
            if(i!= helperArr.length -1) {
                helperString = helperString+"/";
            }
        }
        endArray.push(helperString);
        helperArr.length = helperArr.length-1;
        getParentArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the URL always in the exact same format?

Comment: its more a file path then an URL but yes. It will always begin with a / and always end without a slash. Just the number of elements in the path can vary (like "/branches/test" or "/trunk/test2/anotherElement")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
/* First split the path at any folders separator ('/')*/
var splitPath = "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile".split("/");
/* Initialise a final array to save the paths. Store the first one in there! */
var endPaths = [splitPath[0] + "/"];
/* Check if there are multiple paths available */
if(splitPath.length >= 2){
    /* Run through each and append it to the last saved one, then add it to the results.*/
    for(var i = 1; i <= splitPath.length-1; i++){
        endPaths.push(endPaths[i-1] + splitPath[i] + "/")
    }
}
```

This will include `/` as a path, which is technically a path. If you don't want that, you can use this line instead at the initialisation to exclude any simple paths like that:

```
var endPaths = splitPath[0] != "" ? [splitPath[0] + "/"] : [];
```

If you do the above though, beware that your loop will throw an error as `endPaths[i-1]` will be `undefined` when your loop starts running, you will have to do a check inside your for loop:

```
/* You need to do -2 as you start at 1, but you only want to add paths from 2 upwards.*/
var prevPath = typeof endPaths[i-2] !== "undefined" ? endPaths[i-2] : "";
endPaths.push(prevPath + splitPath[i] + "/")
```

Comment: Thanks this looks much cleaner then the version I came up with. I'll go with this one.

Comment: Good :) I added a little bit as my suggestion for ignoring the initial `/` could throw an error.

Comment: well your edit is not really working for me. But I get the point and will adapt this one to suit my needs. Anyway you helped me with guiding me to the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, because you skip one step in the original Array you actually need to go back two steps, not one. I've amended it. Also, if you do the `for` loop up to `splitPath.length-2` instead of `splitPath.length-1` you exclude the last item as well, as you wanted.

Comment: @dehlen - This is actually the solution that I thought you were describing in the original question.   LOL

Answer (score 4):

Here's a compact solution, but it may not be as clear as @somethinghere 's:

```js
var path= '/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile'.split('/'),
    paths= [];

path.shift();
while(path.length > 1) {
  paths.push((paths[paths.length-1] || '') + '/' + path.shift());
}

alert(paths.join('\r'));
```

**Update**

Thanks for the comments.  Here's a more compact version, which doesn't require splitting or shifting:

```js
var path= '/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile',
    paths= [],
    i = 1;

while(i = path.indexOf('/',i)+1) {
  paths.push(path.substr(0,i));
}

alert(paths.join('\r'));
```

**Update #2**

And just for giggles, a third solution, which should be more legible than my others, but [still a little slower](http://jsperf.com/parent-paths) than @somethinghere 's:

```js
var path= '/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile',
    paths= [],
    i;

for(var i = 1 ; i < path.length ; i++) {
  if(path[i]==='/') paths.push(path.substr(0,i));
}
 
alert(paths.join('\r'));
```

Comment: Was thinking of something like this as well :-)

Comment: giving you an upvote because I like your answer too :)

Comment: There are actually a lot of good, but very different solutions in here . . .

Comment: Yeah I like this as well, but I do find it a tad less legible. Is there an advantage to using `shift()` (as in, would it win some resources compared to the looping solution I used or is the difference negligible?)

Comment: @somethinghere, I agree my first code is less legible than yours.  I've added a new version, which avoids so much array manipulation.  But the single equal sign in the `while` loop might be confusing to some.

Comment: @RickHitchcock that is quite clever tbh. Again makes me wonder if there are resource gains to be had by using split. (I am mostly wondering if using `split()` once is faster than to repeating `indexOf()` - I dont know if its better or worse, or how to measure the speed of execution, I'm just wondering)

Comment: @somethinghere, I've created a jsPerf with your code vs. both of my versions.  Yours is much faster:  http://jsperf.com/parent-paths

Comment: @RickHitchcock O waw, thats cool. I only went from the assumption as redoing a function is probably more intensive than manipulating results. Never seen `jsperf` before, thanks! This will be an invaluable tool :)

Comment: @RickHitchcock Just tested on Safari 8.0.2 and your second one came out on top, so the test might be a bit inconclusive. Still interesting :)

Comment: Yours wins under Chrome, with my third version a relatively close second.  But my second version wins by a landslide under IE11.  It all has to do with how each browser optimizes string and array handling.

Answer (score 1):

And, for a little more variety, a recursive, RegExp-based solution:

```
function iterateMatch(testString, currPattern, results) {
    var regexTestPattern = new RegExp("^" + currPattern + "\/[^\/]+");
    results.push(testString.match(regexTestPattern)[0]);

    if (results[results.length - 1] !== testString) {
        iterateMatch(testString, results[results.length - 1], results)
    }
}
```

The function takes in:

1. the test string,
2. a pattern to "ignore" during the match
3. the array to turn the results to

The "ignore" pattern will start out as a blank string, but, during every iteration, will contain the previously matched directory level.  This string is used as the beginning of the matching pattern, which then adds a RegExp pattern to the end, containing a RegExp pattern to match a forward slash and one or more non-slash characters.

The match is captured in the results array and, if it does not equal the test string, is passed into the `iterateMatch` function again as the next "ignore" pattern (along with the original test string and results array), so that the match starts looking at the next level down.

When called like this, with your test string:

```
var sTestString = "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile";

var sCurrPattern = "";
var aResults = [];

iterateMatch(sTestString, sCurrPattern, aResults);

console.log(aResults);
```

. . . the result is:

```
 ["/branches",
  "/branches/projects",
  "/branches/projects/MyTool",
  "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool",
  "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile"]
```

Comment: Like the use of regex :)

Answer (score 1):

This `reduce` solved my use-case (without a preceding `/`):

```js
const string = "a/b/c/d";
const stringSplits = string.split('/');
const parentArray = stringSplits.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  if (i === 0) return [val]
  acc.push( acc[i-1] + '/' + val )
  return acc
}, []);

// returns ["a", "a/b", "a/b/c", "a/b/c/d"]
```

Or this one-liner if you're absolutely bonkers:

```js
const parentArray = "a/b/c/d".split('/').reduce((acc, val, i) => i === 0 ? [val] : [].concat(acc, acc[i-1] + '/' + val ), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it. Using a little jQuery to help us out makes for a nice concise function (even if it is a bit inefficient).

```js
    function getParentArray(path) {
        // split up on the forward slashes
        var splitPath = path.split('/');
        // Don't need the last part of the path
        splitPath.pop();
        // put an ever growing slice of the original path into a new array
        return $.map(splitPath, function(value, i) {
            return '/' + splitPath.slice(1, i + 1).join('/');
        }).splice(1);
    }

    var samplePath = '/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile';
    var parentArray = getParentArray(samplePath);

    alert(parentArray.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not at all short and not at all elegant... A bit different approach...

```
function split_string_to_path( str ) {
  if (typeof str == "undefined")
    return false; // return, if no string

  split_path = str.split("/"); // splitted string

  result_arr = []; // result paths into this variable
  tmp_arr = []; // temporary, for join

  for( i = 0; i < split_path.length; i++ ) { // loop through all elements
    tmp_arr.push( split_path[i] ); // push element
    result_path = tmp_arr.join( "/" );

    if ( result_path.length > 0 )
      result_arr.push( tmp_arr.join( "/" ) ); // join tmp arr to path and add it to result_arr
  }

  return result_arr;
}

split_result = split_string_to_path( "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile" ); // run function

console.log( split_result ); // output on console
```

Comment: There are many imporvement to be made, For example, instead of `if(typeof str === "undefined")` you could simply use `if(!str)`, as str will be `falsy` but can be checked against (as its defined in the function). Since the variable `str` is not used after splitting, you could rewrite the `split()` into `str` itself to avoid making anothing variable and thereby saving resources. Also, and its just a sidenote, but I think your function should be named `split_path_to_string` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var str = "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile"
, d = "/"
, arr = str.split(d).filter(Boolean)
, res = arr.map(function(val, i) {
            return i < 1 ? d + val : d + arr.slice(0, i).join(d) + d + arr[i] 
  }).slice(0, arr.length - 1);
```

```js
    var str = "/branches/projects/MyTool/MyTool/someOtherFolderOrFile"
    , d = "/"
    , arr = str.split(d).filter(Boolean)
    , res = arr.map(function(val, i) {
              return i < 1 ? d + val : d + arr.slice(0, i).join(d) + d + arr[i] 
      }).slice(0, arr.length - 1); 

document.querySelectorAll("pre")[0].innerText = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```